# Can I look up wikipedia articles on the command line?

Tags: command-line

I have a list of well-known authors that I'm trying to find data for, specifically their gender and nationality. Is there a way to query this on the command line? Like `curl something-magic.com 'Frances Burney'` and have it retrieve a nice paragraph that I can then mine for information about gender and nationality? Or better yet, something more structured that I can parse easier? I'm on Linux, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are lucky and your author exists in wiki AND his/her name exists there only once (non-ambiguous), then you can use this approach:

```
$ cat mywiki.sh

NAME=$(echo $@ | tr " " "_")

wget -O $NAME.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$NAME
lynx -dump $NAME.html > $NAME.txt
dataurl=$(awk 'sub(/.*www.\wikidata\.org/, "http://wikidata.org") {print; exit}' $NAME.txt)
lynx -dump -nolist $dataurl > $NAME.dat
```

This way, you will have the html code of the page, a txt with the same info but without html tags and a dat with contains the main data of the author (and the wiki page) in fact lines. Another filter script can be written to filter these files and write a csv/html table which when opened, it's easy to have an overview of what must be researched manually.

Comment: I fixed the abiguity problem by running this script on both the author's name and the author's name with ` (writer)` appended. Works great!